# Can I extend a custom Application in Espresso?

Tags: android, dagger, android-espresso

I'm attempting to set up Dagger in my Espresso instrumentation tests in order to mock out calls to external resources (RESTful services in this case).  The pattern I followed in Robolectric for my unit testing was to extend my production Application class and override the Dagger modules with test modules which will return mocks.  I'm attempting to do the same thing here, but I'm getting a ClassCastException in my Espresso tests when I try to cast the application to my custom application.

Here is my set up thus far:

**Production**

Under app/src/main/java/com/mypackage/injection I have:

**MyCustomApplication**

```
package com.mypackage.injection;

import android.app.Application;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import dagger.ObjectGraph;

public class MyCustomApplication extends Application {

    protected ObjectGraph graph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<Object>();
        modules.add(new AndroidModule(this));
        modules.add(new RemoteResourcesModule(this));
        modules.add(new MyCustomModule());

        return modules;
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        graph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

Which I use in the following manner:

**BaseActivity**

```
package com.mypackage.injection.views;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomApplication;

public abstract class MyCustomBaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((MyCustomApplication)getApplication()).inject(this);
    }

}
```

Activity under test

```
package com.mypackage.views.mydomain;
// imports snipped for bevity

public class MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //snip
    }
}
```

**Espresso Setup**

Under app/src/androidTest/java/com/mypackage/injection I have:

**MyCustomEspressoApplication**

```
package com.mypackage.injection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import dagger.ObjectGraph;

public class MyCustomEspressoApplication extends MyCustomApplication {

    private AndroidModule androidModule;
    private MyCustomModule myCustomModule;
    private EspressoRemoteResourcesModule espressoRemoteResourcesModule;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        List<Object> modules = new ArrayList<Object>();
        modules.add(getAndroidModule());
        modules.add(getEspressoRemoteResourcesModule());
        modules.add(getMyCustomModule());

        return modules;
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        graph.inject(object);
    }

    public AndroidModule getAndroidModule() {
        if (this.androidModule == null) {
            this.androidModule = new AndroidModule(this);
        }

        return this.androidModule;
    }

    public MyCustomModule getMyCustomModule() {
        if (this.myCustomModule == null) {
            this.myCustomModule = new MyCustomModule();
        }

        return this.myCustomModule;
    }

    public EspressoRemoteResourcesModule getEspressoRemoteResourcesModule() {
        if (this.espressoRemoteResourcesModule == null) {
            this.espressoRemoteResourcesModule = new EspressoRemoteResourcesModule();
        }

        return this.espressoRemoteResourcesModule;
    }
}
```

My Espresso test, under app/src/androidTest/com/mypackage/espresso:

```
package com.mypackage.espresso;

// imports snipped for brevity

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MyActivityTest extends   ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity>{

    private MyActivity myActivity;

    public MyActivityTest() {
        super(MyActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        myActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

     @Test
     public void testWhenTheActionBarButtonIsPressedThenThePlacesAreListed() {
         //The next line is where the runtime exception occurs.
         MyCustomEspressoApplication app = (MyCustomEspressoApplication)getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        //I've also tried getActivity().getApplication() and 
        // getActivity.getApplicationContext() with the same results
        //snip
     }
}
```

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

(I've seen lots of answers regarding the ClassCastException in custom Application classes before, and most of them point to a missing "android:name" property on the Application node.  I'm pasting this here to show that this is not the case as far as I can tell.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mypackage">   
    <!-- snip --> 
    <application
        android:name=".injection.MyCustomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- snip -->
    </application>
<!-- snip -->
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'idea'

android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
   packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':swipeablecardview')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0'
    compile ('com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'javawriter'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'javawriter'
    }
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    //    compile 'se.walkercrou:google-places-api-java:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-SNAPSHOT')
    testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-SNAPSHOT')
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject'
        exclude module: 'javawriter'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1')
}
```

The stacktrace:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomApplication cannot be cast to
>   com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication at
>   com.mypackage.espresso.MyActivityTest.testWhenTheActionBarButtonIsPressedThenThePlacesAreListed(MyActivityTest.java:107)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136) at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:270)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)

I've read through the Espresso and Dagger docs and searched through issues on Github to no avail.  I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide.  Thanks in advance.

**Edit #1**

I followed Daniel's suggestion to extend the test runner and checkout the VerifyError, and got the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
            at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
            at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
            at com.mypackage.injection.EspressoRemoteResourcesModule.<init>(EspressoRemoteResourcesModule.java:17)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication.getEspressoRemoteResourcesModule(MyCustomEspressoApplication.java:52)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication.getModules(MyCustomEspressoApplication.java:24)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomApplication.onCreate(MyCustomApplication.java:18)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication.onCreate(MyCustomEspressoApplication.java:16)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
            at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
            at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
            at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
            at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
            at com.mypackage.injection.EspressoRemoteResourcesModule.<init>(EspressoRemoteResourcesModule.java:17)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication.getEspressoRemoteResourcesModule(MyCustomEspressoApplication.java:52)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication.getModules(MyCustomEspressoApplication.java:24)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomApplication.onCreate(MyCustomApplication.java:18)
            at com.mypackage.injection.MyCustomEspressoApplication.onCreate(MyCustomEspressoApplication.java:16)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 06:40:28.594    1016-1016/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Error in app com.mypackage running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.test/com.mypackage.EspressoTestRunner}:
04-29 06:40:28.594    1016-1016/? W/ActivityManager﹕ java.lang.VerifyError
04-29 06:40:28.594    1016-1016/? W/ActivityManager﹕ java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils
```

This pointed me at Mockito.  I was missing the necessary mockito and dexmaker libraries.

I updated my dependencies to:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile ('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2') {
    exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    exclude module: 'mockito-core'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
     exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}
```

I also overrode MyCustomModule, which needed to include EspressoRemoteResourcesModule.  Once I did this things started working.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With a custom instrumentation runner, you can override `newApplication` and have it instantiate something other than the default application from the manifest.

```
public class MyRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
  @Override
  public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
      throws Exception {
    return super.newApplication(cl, MyCustomEspressoApplication.class.getName(), context);
  }
}
```

Be sure to update `testInstrumentationRunner` with your custom runner's name.

Comment: Tried this, now I get: 

Tests on nexus_5_android_4_0_3(AVD) - 4.1.1 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.VerifyError'
:app:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[nexus_5_android_4_0_3(AVD) - 4.1.1] [31mFAILED [0m
No tests found.

This seems to be breaking new ground.  Is there another method I need to override to get it to detect tests?

Comment: Can you paste the full `VerifyError` (should be in logcat I think) and any `dalvikvm` warnings? `No tests found` usually means there was an error during the runner's setup, before tests started.

Comment: See my edit above.  The TL;DR version is that you pointed me in the right direction by extending the test runner and examining the VerifyError, which pointed me to Mockito and Dexmaker.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: this only works in the androidTest folder, but I'm using Robolectric that requires to be in the test folder. How can I use both?

Answer (score 28):

Took me an entire day to get the complete answer.

**Step 1: Override AndroidJUnitRunner**

```
public class TestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner
{
    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication.class.getName(), context);
    }
}
```

**Step 2: replace the existing AndroidJunitRunner in build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    // testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'com.xi_zz.androidtest.TestRunner'
}
```

**Step 3: Add com.android.support.test:runner to build.gradle**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

**Step 4: Only if you got this error**

```
Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (25.2.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

Then, add one more line:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

**Finally, test if it works**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MockApplicationTest
{
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testApplicationName() throws Exception
    {
        assertEquals("TestApplication", mActivityRule.getActivity().getApplication().getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved me my day! Thanks. I ran into an error "Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}" even though I used custom test runner as you suggested. Solution for this is to delete the configuration (`android studio -> Run > Edit Configurations > Delete everything under Android Instrumentation Tests`). Now run the tests again.

Comment: @rpattabi I deleted everything but I got error again :( and all configuration came back. what is wrong with Android studio! I try to do it with console but I get error from there too.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to figure this out for a while and this works perfectly. :)

Comment: This answer is much more in detail. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I haven't tried this extensively all cases, but you can try a custom Rule to specify your Custom Application class per test case instead of for all test cases applied by the custom runner. I've had success with the following in simple cases:

```
public class ApplicationTestRule<T extends Application> extends UiThreadTestRule {
    Class<T> appClazz;
    boolean wait = false;
    T app;

    public ApplicationTestRule(Class<T> applicationClazz) {
        this(applicationClazz, false);
    }

    public ApplicationTestRule(Class<T> applicationClazz, boolean wait) {
        this.appClazz = applicationClazz;
        this.wait = wait;
    }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return new ApplicationStatement(super.apply(base, description));
    }

    private void terminateApp() {
        if (app != null) {
            app.onTerminate();
        }
    }

    public void createApplication() throws IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {
        app = (T) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().newApplication(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), appClazz.getName(), InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().callApplicationOnCreate(app);
    }

    private class ApplicationStatement extends Statement {

        private final Statement mBase;

        public ApplicationStatement(Statement base) {
            mBase = base;
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            try {
                if (!wait) {
                    createApplication();
                }
                mBase.evaluate();
            } finally {
                terminateApp();
                app = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your test case, create the rule:

```
@Rule
public ApplicationTestRule<TestApplication> appRule = new ApplicationTestRule<>(TestApplication.class,true);
```

Note the second parameter is optional. If false or left off, the custom application is created each time before each test case. If set to true, you need to call `appRule.createApplication()` before your Application logic.

Comment: Note that doing this will create the application, but it does not prevent the original application class from starting first on its own. Daniel's answer above replaces the actual instrumentation runner, allowing you to inject your mock application class every time an app is requested, not just during individual test rules.

Answer (score 8):

If you're testing a library module you can make a custom application class and register it in the test package manifest:

**root/library-module/src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:name="path.to.TestApplication" />
</manifest>
```

No rules, no runners.

Comment: Does this only work for library modules, and not app modules? Because I tried with the latter, and it did not work at all.

Comment: @AutonomousApps Haven't tried it, but in an app module you'll want to test the actual app, no?

Comment: I want a subclass of the actual app for my instrumented tests so I can override the default dagger graph. For example, I don't want to make real API calls, or use Fabric/Crashlytics, but stub these functions. Your comment is confusing because it questions the very premise of the original question and even your own answer. If we should always use the "real app", why ever try to override it, be it in an app or library module?

Answer (score 1):

Roboelectric Configuration [here](http://robolectric.org/configuring/) can save if only need is separate application for test. following would help

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@Config(application = MockApp::class)
class RegisTests {
    @Test
    fun hello(){

        val acs = ActivityScenario.launch(RegistrationActivity::class.java)
        acs.moveToState(State.CREATED)
        Truth.assertWithMessage("No created").that(State.CREATED).isEqualTo(acs.state)
   

 }
}
```