# Using Android res bools.xml from androidTest directly?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I have a bool resource called `should_init_data` that I want to have different values for in `src/main` vs `src/androidTest`.

So I created it in `src/main/res/values/bools.xml`. I want to override this value during `androidTest` - but it's not working with a `src/androidTest/res/values/bools.xml` file with that value overidden.

How do I fix this? Why is this something that the Android Gradle Plugin does not support?

Comment: You should test a specif buldType or a flavor. Why are you trying to override some values in test?

Comment: because my application class automatically starts initializing data via an intent service based on the value of a shared preference. this causes an SQLDatabaseLockedException in instrumentation tests if the service is running. there's no way for me to hook into the application class fast enough to manually set that preference to false. So, I want to tell my application class to not automatically start initializing the data during testing.

Comment: Not sure about it, but you can use a custom Application class only for test.check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750164/can-i-extend-a-custom-application-in-espresso