# Test Android Activity with different Application class

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I´m looking for a way to test an Activity with JUnit4 and the ActivityTestRule, but with a different application class (e.g. mocked or inherited). I was able to get this for library projects using the manifest merge and tools:replace="android:name" on the application tag in the androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml. This however does not work for applications.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can subclass the `AndroidJUnitRunner` with your own runner and override `newApplication()` with your custom application class.

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

@Override
public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return super.newApplication(cl, CustomTestApplication.class.getName(), context);
}
}
```

Make sure to update your build.gradle with the new runner like this:

`testInstrumentationRunner "com.mypackage.name.path.CustomTestRunner"`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out: testInstrumentationRunner "com.mypackage.name.path.CustomTestRunner". Many other tutorials failed to do so.

Comment: Also, if you're running your test out of Android Studio, you may need to update your `Specific instrumentation runner` in your Run/Debug Configuration to point to your CustomTestRunner equivalent.

Comment: Is there a way where I can specify some of the test should use `A` as the application class and others use `B` ? Like I want some tests to use Application with dependency injection and some others without.

Comment: @Sreekanth this can be done via custom test rule. See this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778841/2957893 . Note that it still somehow runs your app but then executes overridenn App class per test

Comment: I can't extend AndroidJUnitRunner. Where can I put to custom runner?