# How can I provide custom Application class for Unit Test in Android Project

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing, android-unit-testing

I need a context in some unit test classes. I'm getting errors from 3rd SDKs when I try to provide an application class. So, I want to provide an empty application class for the unit tests.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SampleTest {

    private val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33959671/7210237) (with an answer). Take a look.