# Custom application class with Espresso 2.2

Tags: android, android-espresso

how can I define my own App class to be used by Espresso? I tried my own AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner but I couldn't find any useful method over there..

Comment: What you need is something that has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29889514/8268378).