# Android - Mock method of Application during instrumented test

Tags: android, testing, mocking, mockito, android-espresso

Assuming my Application class is like following:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    public String example(){
        return "Test";
    }

}
```

I have some instrumented tests for testing UI. Assuming I have the following test:

```
public class MyMainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void firstTest(){
       onView(withId(R.id.textBt)).perform(click());
       // ...
    }
}
```

I want to mock `example()` method inside `MyMainActivityTest`, let's say that it should return `Mock Test` instead of `Test`. How to do it?

Comment: Why -1? Is my question unclear?

Comment: don't know why it was downvoted. ill answer in few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create Class which extends your `Application` class and put it into test folder.

```
    public class MyTestApp extends MyApp {

    public String example(){
        return "SuperTest";
    }
}
```

Then use `@Config` Annotation from Robolectric library over your test class:

```
@Config(application = MyTestApp)
```

This should work for all kind of tests including Espresso UI tests, if it isn't you can try to use custom TestRunner with your TestApp class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29889514/3416163):

```
public class MyRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
  @Override
  public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
      throws Exception {
    return super.newApplication(cl, MyTestApp.class.getName(), context);
  }
}
```

And put this over your Test class:
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)